# Why would you want to create an empty class in ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

In the description on the left side panel, it says,

"The demo code we're about to show you includes a fancy trick: if you want to end a Ruby statement without going to a new line, you can just type a semicolon. This is a time saver when you're writing something very short, like an empty class or method definition."

Why would we wan to make an empty class? Why wouldn't we just leave it blank?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: It depends on your intentions.. [example](https://gist.github.com/panthomakos/1230673#file-group-rb-L3) and [example](https://gist.github.com/panthomakos/1230704#file-group-rb-L3-L5)

Comment: Is your question about empty case or empty class?

Comment: What left side panel?

Comment: What is wan? .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want a custom error class that does nothing special except use its name to convey something:

```
class MySpecialError < Error; end
```

Or you may want to start by declaring a class and then tack on your  functionality later (no problem with that because ruby classes are dynamic):

```
class Foo; end
def Foo.frobnicate; "something" ; end
```

Though in ruby, you could just as well do

```
Foo = Class.new
```

(The difference is that `class Foo; end` won't clear an already existing Foo class, whereas with `Class.new` you're starting from scratch).